# Magento does not use simple HMVC like all the frameworks use why?

Tags: magento

I can not understand why Magento has developed this kind of architecture? Why they
want to make Magento different from others?

Comment: not a programming question, may want to ask this over at http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! to suggest me, will raise this question on magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's actually a fairly clever architecture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?